# Using Apache variable

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, http-headers, mod-auth

I'm trying to use Apache's OpenID authentication module. According to [this page](http://findingscience.com/mod_auth_openid/), I should be able to use the `REMOTE_USER` Apache variable to identify the user. I'd like to pass this as a header to an upstream application (I'm using Apache to authenticate and reverse-proxy).

My Apache site config is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

  <Location />
    AuthType OpenID
    require valid-user
    AuthOpenIDAXRequire email http://axschema.org/contact/email @muller\.io$
    AuthOpenIDAXUsername email
    RequestHeader set x-username $REMOTE_USER
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've searched and searched, but the most I can find is how to use an environment variable in this context. I've verified that a hard-coded string works (actually the above passes the string `"$REMOTE_USER"` to my application).

If `mod_auth_openid` is setting the `REMOTE_USER` variable *within Apache*, how can I then pass that upstream to my app?

Comment: Try replacing $REMOTE_USER with %{REMOTE_USER}

Comment: I did try that as well as `%{REMOTE_USER}e`. The first errored out with `Unrecognized header format %` on Apache restart, while the second gave `(null)` in the expected header on my app.

Comment: The infuriating part is that it correctly rejects emails that aren't from `muller.io`; I've verified that. The emails just aren't making it to the app!

Answer (score 1):

After digging some more, I found [this page](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/140281) with the following code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
 RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
 RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
```

This was the magic bullet that fixed it for me. I read some pages that suggest this may be incorrect (and indeed it looks kludgy), so please feel free to recommend something better.

Comment: Beat me to this post.  I was going to recommend something very similar from https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/83067 - This thread also explains why its neccessary.